# How many levels do pokemon have in Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know your trainer has a level from 1-40, but the game doesn't show what level your pokemon are.

I've seen charts listing pokemon levels go up to 40 or 40.5, and sometimes even up to 80. Some of them mention "half-levels".

What's the real answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a stat calculator at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wbtIc33K45iU1ScUnkB0PlslJ-eLaJlSZY47sPME2Uk/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true# that does various calculations for pokemon to work out among other things max stats.

In that spreadsheet the pokemon level can go up to 40.5. I believe that this terminology is used because 40 is the highest player level and your pokemon max level is tied to your character level. Each character level up allows you to boost your pokemon twice which is why the half level terminology is used here.

Obviously the number for the level is a relatively arbitrary one and you could as easily use just whole numbers as would be more traditional to get a max level of 80.

Comment: So a boost is a half-level, and you can do it twice for each of your trainer levels. So at level 1, you can get a pokemon from 1->1.5->2. Wouldn't this mean max level for pokemon is 40->40.5->**41**? And if we use the 80 level terminology, max is 80->81->**82**?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe that at level one your pokemon can be either level 1 or 1.5. So there are two possible pokemon levels per character level. Trainer 1 = 1/1.5, trainer 2 adds 2/2.5. Trainer level 40 adds 40/40.5. As you can see with 2 levels per character on the integer character scale that would be 1-80 (trainer 1 allows 1,2; trainer 2 allows 3,4; trainer 40 allows 79,80).

Comment: I think I get it now. So pokemon can be powered up once "beyond" your trainer level, so max pokemon level = your level, +1 power up. And "+1 power up" can be equal to +0.5 or +1, depending on if you are using a 40 (half) or 80 (full) level scale.

Comment: Yeah, if using the half scale you can go one beyond (to level.5). For the 80 scale you can go up to double your level (so level 18 could be pokemon level 36, level 40 up to pokemon 80, level 1 up to pokemon 2). As I mentioned in my answer given it never explicitly uses a pokemon level anywhere there is no right or wrong scale and somebody else could easily be using something different. Though having said that I think the two mentioned are the two obvious ones. But its probably important to try to understand from the context of whoever is talking about levels what they actually mean.

Comment: You say that "it never explicitly uses a pokemon level anywhere there is no right or wrong scale". So pokemon levels are arbitrary? I have heard there is a "CpMultiplier" used internally by the game, and that this is what levels are really referring to.

Comment: Its more the labels that are used are arbitrary. The concept of levels definitely seems to exist (and you are right that they are basically tied to a multiplier) but because the game doesn't label them at all its down to people to call them what they want to.

Comment: Accepting this answer now because it is basically correct, minus a few details from my research. Max Poke level should be 40 just like the trainer, not an extra half level (40.5). Also, for some reason at level 1 you can power up a pokemon an extra 2 times (up to 2.5). So your pokemons' current max level is actually your trainer level +1.5. Theoretically this means max poke level could be 41.5, but what people believe now is that it is still 40 because CpMultiplier values stopped there.

Comment: The spreadsheet I linked in my answer goes from 1 to 40.5. You could probably count from 0.5 to 40 if you wanted to but this goes into what I said about the numbers being relatively arbitrary.

Comment: I know I could start counting levels at "-1" if I wanted, but that's not really what I meant this time. I'll try to explain using a less ambiguous term... like CpMulitplier. So my point was that it's generally assumed now that pokemon can have a max CpMulitplier of 0.7903, not 0.7931 as shown on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes more sense. I hadn't looked far into the source of the data I was referring to and just assumed that if that value was there it had been datamined from somewhere. I might suggest that you either edit my answer with better references or create a new answer with those references (the latter might be better, I suspect, since it sounds like you are correcting a lot of my answer).

Comment: That's interesting. I'm pretty new here, so I didn't realize I could edit other people's answers.

Comment: I have no idea what the rep requirement is. I think you should be able to though. It might require approval by somebody else though, I can't recall.

Comment: I have been wondering about the max pokemon level.  It seems we need a level 40 trainer to verify for us all.  But my initial thought follows @dragonfire first comment that 40 cpMultipliers should mean level 41 is max.